# javascript tablesorter pager plugin

Tags: javascript, tablesorter

I use tablesorter and it works fine, 
but when I add code for tablesorter.pager plugin tablesorter stop work ( only icons to sort are displayed) and table sorter doesn't work too.

without tablesorter.pager plugin (sorting works) :

```
    $(function() {
 $("table")
   .tablesorter({
    headers: {
      1: {sorter: false},
      3: {sorter: false},
      6: {sorter: false},
      7: {sorter: 'mydate'},
      8: {sorter: 'mydate'},
      10: {sorter: 'lifetime'}
      },
    widthFixed: true,
    widgets: ['zebra']
    });
```

with tablesorter.pager plugin doesn't work sorting and pagging.

```
$(function() {
 $("table")
   .tablesorter({
    headers: {
      1: {sorter: false},
      3: {sorter: false},
      6: {sorter: false},
      7: {sorter: 'mydate'},
      8: {sorter: 'mydate'},
      10: {sorter: 'lifetime'}
      },
    widthFixed: true,
    widgets: ['zebra']
   })
  .tablesorterPager({
    container: $("#pager"),
     size: 20      
    });
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in console?

Comment: Yes, I had error and I found a solution !

ERROR: 

Type $.browser is undefined

I need include this script

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js

after you include your jquery javascript file and now it works!

Thanks!